# I want my script to run two active loops along side each other

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I have [a script](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/05e746bf95d6d49632ba38df07a09f12) that plays audio files when I press a key via pygame.

I can play the drums (kick, snare, hat) and it is quite cool - now I want to build on it more.  I have two things I want to achieve both of which require me to have *2 active loops running alongside each other*.

#### Scenario 1:

Imagine I have an audio file of a piano riff that just loops over and over.  I want to be able to hold a key, (in [my code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/05e746bf95d6d49632ba38df07a09f12) it is the d key), and that audio file will play until a) I unpress the d key. Or b) The audio file reaches it's end.
I have achieved this but the part I need to learn is **how can I scan for more keys being pressed *while* the piano riff loops behind it?**  In my code, pressing the d key calls to a function that plays the piano loop and waits for d to unpress.

#### Scenario 2 is basically the same:

In my code, pressing the e key calls a function that uses a loop and time.sleep to play a standard drum beat.  **how can I scan/play more keys/sounds *while* the 'drumloop' plays drums until e key is unpressed?**

Thanks for any guidance.  I think my solution will either be make a function that scans for keys that I call after every and all keypresses (instead of making the key scanning loop the main loop)..
Or something about "multithreading" - which I would be interested in learning about if it can help me to multiple tasks in python at once.

Comment: Please take the [tour] ans see [mcve] as you should not rely on external link for your question

Comment: You might want to take a look at [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). But this generally is not what you should ask on SO, instead write code and when you have issues with that code we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two have to loops running at the same time I suggest threads. Threads come pre-installed with python 3 and it would look like this.

```
from _thread import *

def loop2():
    while True:
        #your sound loop thing

start_new_thread(loop2,())

while True:
    #your other loop thing
```